# How can I move h2 tag into center of div?

Tags: html, css

I have this div :

```html
    <div id="ShowCase" style="background-color: black; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; opacity: 0.5;  color: white;">
            <h2 >شما با این گزینه می توانید</h2>
    </div>
```

want to show h2 tag into ShowCase div center,but I am getting this output:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Make the h2 an inline-block and make the parent have text-align: center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking just horizontally aligning the text; just add

```
#ShowCase {
   text-align: center;
}
```

If you're talking vertical aligned, then you can use `flexbox` or `display:table`. I've written out the `display:table` method as it is has more browser compatibility.

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
}

#ShowCase {
  background-color: black; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px; 
  opacity: 0.5; 
  color: white;
  
  /* Horizonatally Centers Text -- */
  text-align: center;
  
  /* Needed in order to Vertically Center Text --*/
   display: table; 

}

/* Vertically Aligns Text -- */
#ShowCase h2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowCase">
        <h2>شما با این گزینه می توانید</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use text-align:center in h2 tag

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowCase">
        <h2>شما با این گزینه می توانید</h2>
</div>
```

If you want to set it as center vertically also then try in this way--

```css
#ShowCase
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: table;
  background:blue;
  
}

h2{
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
 
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowCase">
        <h2>شما با این گزینه می توانید</h2>
</div>
```

Here showcase height and width is as like your screen width and height.

Comment: create,but just set center of top of screen,but want to center of screen,ShowCase fit screen,and want h2 show center of ShowCase

Comment: use `flexbox` layout for container of `h2` and specify content position like this `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` to center it vertically

Answer (score 0):

you can adjust it with text-align or with margin,but I would recommend you to go with text-align

Here I have removed your display:none and used text-algin:center

```css
#ShowCase{
  background-color: black; 
  position: absolute; 
  height: 100%; width: 100%; 
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}
h2{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowCase">
        <h2>شما با این گزینه می توانید</h2>
</div>
```